# Where to put a xsl file in Grails, and how to get the path

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to pass my xsl and read file on the service to generate pdf. i always get an error meesage something like

Document is empty (something might be wrong with your XSLT stylesheet).. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Document is empty (something might be wrong with your XSLT stylesheet).

i also autowire the file on the bean resource.xml or resource.groovy

```
class MyClassHolder{
   Resource template
}

//in my controller

class MyController{
   method(){
   File resource = classHolder.template.file
   def reader = new FileReader(resource)
   myservice.convert(reader)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I required to put some file and read content from that file I create a directory e.g. `resources` in the `web-app` directory and read content in service like:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH

class MyService {
    def readFile() {
        def servletContext = SCH.servletContext
        def file = servletContext.getResource('/resources/example.xsl').getContent()
        println "Content = ${file}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put it in the web-app folder, and you are using Grails 2, you can use the Grails Resource Locator.

```
class MyService {
    def grailsResourceLocator
    def templateResource

    @PostConstruct
    init() {
        templateResource = grailsResourceLocator.findResourceForURI('/resources/example.xsl')
    }
    def convert() {
        // no need to pass in resource or filereader, can use file or inputStream
        def templateFile = templateResource.file
        def templateStream = templateResource.inputStream
    }
}
class MyController {
    MyService myService

    method() {
        myService.convert()
    }
}
```

Handy tip: to mock this in Spock, use GroovyPageStaticResourceLoader

```
@TestFor(MyService)
class MyServiceSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {
        service.grailsResourceLocator = Mock(GroovyPageStaticResourceLocator)
    }
}
```